How to force text to overflow its parent container width?
I have a somewhat long label in a DropdownButtonFormField and I need to show the entire text which overflows outside it's parent container.
How can I achieve that?

Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
    child: new DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: ("Long Text here, which should overflow it's parent"),
        // labelStyle: new TextStyle(
        //   overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        // ),
        // label: TextField(
        //   //maxLines: 1,
        //   style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible,),
        //   decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
        //       hintText: ("Long Text here, which should overflow it's parent"),
        //   ),
        // ),
        // label: Text(
        //   ("Long Text here, which should overflow it's parent"),
        //     overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        // ),
      ),
      isExpanded:true,
      hint: Text("Select"),
      items: _list.map((value) {
        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: new Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {},
    )
),


it'd be better if you didn't, given that there is no guarantee that text will even be visible? If you have a super long dropdown label, switch from "just labels in your dropdown" to "short labels in your dropdown" that automatically set a guide text underneath the dropdown.

Actually the text is not that long and only the last word overflows the container. It's currently not displayed and this is the problem. You can assume the text to display is Long Text here, which.

Solution 1:
Increase the width of the Container to occupy a larger portion of the screen. You can do this by setting its width to a percentage of the screen width:
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,

Solution 2:
If you need multiple containers or elements within a Column, you can assign each element a specific width. Here's an example:
Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Long Text here, which should overflow it\'s parent',
                              ),
                              // SizedBox(height: 8),
                              Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                      0.30,
                                  child:
                                      new DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        // labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                                        //   overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                                        // ),
                                        // label: TextField(
                                        //   //maxLines: 1,
                                        //   style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible,),
                                        //   decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                        //       hintText: ("[![Long Text here, which should overflow it's parent][1]][1]"),
                                        //   ),
                                        // ),
                                        // label: Text(
                                        //   ("Long Text here, which should overflow it's parent"),
                                        //     overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                                        // ),
                                        ),
                                    isExpanded: true,
                                    hint: Text("Select"),
                                    items: _list.map((value) {
                                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                        value: value,
                                        child: new Text(value),
                                      );
                                    }).toList(),
                                    onChanged: (value) {},
                                  )),


Thanks, I chose the second solution. I was thinking about doing this as well, just was wondering whether there's a better alternative.
